# Virtually turn vector of struct into vector of struct members

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that takes a vector-like input. To simplify things, let's use this `print_in_order` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename vectorlike>
void print_in_order(std::vector<int> const & order,
                    vectorlike const & printme) {
    for (int i : order)
        std::cout << printme[i] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> printme = {100, 200, 300};
    std::vector<int> order = {2,0,1};
    print_in_order(order, printme);
}
```

Now I have a `vector<Elem>` and want to print a single integer member, `Elem.a`, for each Elem in the vector. I could do this by creating a new `vector<int>` (copying `a` for all Elems) and pass this to the print function - however, I feel like there must be a way to pass a "virtual" vector that, when `operator[]` is used on it, returns this only the member `a`. Note that I don't want to change the `print_in_order` function to access the member, it should remain general.

Is this possible, maybe with a lambda expression?
Full code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Elem {
    int a,b;
    Elem(int a, int b) : a(a),b(b) {}
};

template <typename vectorlike>
void print_in_order(std::vector<int> const & order,
                    vectorlike const & printme) {
    for (int i : order)
        std::cout << printme[i] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Elem> printme = {Elem(1,100), Elem(2,200), Elem(3,300)};
    std::vector<int> order = {2,0,1};

    // how to do this?
    virtual_vector X(printme) // behaves like a std::vector<Elem.a>
    print_in_order(order, X);
}
```

Comment: Write your own class that wraps a vector and overloads `[]` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using member pointers you can implement a proxy type that will allow you view a container of objects by substituting each object by one of it's members (see [pointer to data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members)) or by one of it's getters (see [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions)). The first solution addresses only data members, the second accounts for both.

The container will necessarily need to know which container to use and which member to map, which will be provided at construction. The type of a pointer to member depends on the type of that member so it will have to be considered as an additional template argument.

```
template<class Container, class MemberPtr>
class virtual_vector
{
public:
    virtual_vector(const Container & p_container, MemberPtr p_member_ptr) :
        m_container(&p_container),
        m_member(p_member_ptr) 
    {}

private:
    const Container * m_container;
    MemberPtr m_member;
};
```

Next, implement the `operator[]` operator, since you mentioned that it's how you wanted to access your elements. The syntax for dereferencing a member pointer can be surprising at first.

```
template<class Container, class MemberPtr>
class virtual_vector
{
public:
    virtual_vector(const Container & p_container, MemberPtr p_member_ptr) :
        m_container(&p_container),
        m_member(p_member_ptr) 
    {}

    // Dispatch to the right get method
    auto operator[](const size_t p_index) const 
    {
        return (*m_container)[p_index].*m_member;
    }

private:
    const Container * m_container;
    MemberPtr m_member;
};
```

To use this implementation, you would write something like this :

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Elem> printme = { Elem(1,100), Elem(2,200), Elem(3,300) };
    std::vector<int> order = { 2,0,1 };

    virtual_vector<decltype(printme), decltype(&Elem::a)> X(printme, &Elem::a);
    print_in_order(order, X);
}
```

This is a bit cumbersome since there is no template argument deduction happening. So lets add a free function to deduce the template arguments.

```
template<class Container, class MemberPtr>
virtual_vector<Container, MemberPtr>
make_virtual_vector(const Container & p_container, MemberPtr p_member_ptr) 
{
    return{ p_container, p_member_ptr };
}
```

The usage becomes :

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Elem> printme = { Elem(1,100), Elem(2,200), Elem(3,300) };
    std::vector<int> order = { 2,0,1 };

    auto X = make_virtual_vector(printme, &Elem::a);
    print_in_order(order, X);
}
```

If you want to support member functions, it's a little bit more complicated. First, the syntax to dereference a data member pointer is slightly different from calling a function member pointer. You have to implement two versions of the `operator[]` and enable the correct one based on the member pointer type. Luckily the standard provides [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) (both in the [`<type_trait>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header) which allow us to do just that. The member function pointer requires you to specify the arguments to pass to the function (non in this case) and an extra set of parentheses around the expression that would evaluate to the function to call (everything before the list of arguments).

```
template<class Container, class MemberPtr>
class virtual_vector
{
public:
    virtual_vector(const Container & p_container, MemberPtr p_member_ptr) :
        m_container(&p_container),
        m_member(p_member_ptr) 
    {}

    // For mapping to a method
    template<class T = MemberPtr>
    auto operator[](std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<T>::value == true, const size_t> p_index) const
    {
        return ((*m_container)[p_index].*m_member)();
    }

    // For mapping to a member
    template<class T = MemberPtr>
    auto operator[](std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer<T>::value == false, const size_t> p_index) const
    {
        return (*m_container)[p_index].*m_member;
    }

private:
    const Container * m_container;
    MemberPtr m_member;
};
```

To test this, I've added a getter to the `Elem` class, for illustrative purposes.

```
struct Elem {
    int a, b;
    int foo() const { return a; }
    Elem(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

And here is how it would be used :

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Elem> printme = { Elem(1,100), Elem(2,200), Elem(3,300) };
    std::vector<int> order = { 2,0,1 };

    {   // print member
        auto X = make_virtual_vector(printme, &Elem::a);
        print_in_order(order, X);
    }
    {   // print method
        auto X = make_virtual_vector(printme, &Elem::foo);
        print_in_order(order, X);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I also realize that there seems to be no one-liner solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really possible to directly do what you want. Instead you might want to take a hint from the [standard algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) where you take an *extra* argument that is a function-like object that you call for each element. Then you could easily pass a lambda function that prints only the wanted element.

Perhaps something like

```
template<typename vectorlike, typename functionlike>
void print_in_order(std::vector<int> const & order,
                vectorlike const & printme,
                functionlike func) {
    for (int i : order)
        func(printme[i]);
}
```

Then call it like

```
print_in_order(order, printme, [](Elem const& elem) {
    std::cout << elem.a;
});
```

Since C++ have function overloading you can still keep the old `print_in_order` function for plain vectors.

Comment: Since your function is totally general, probably should not be called `print_in_order` any more, maybe `for_each_in_order` or `apply_in_order`.

Comment: You could re-arrange it to still be `print_in_order`: `[](Elem const& elem) -> Elem::a const & { return elem.a; }` and `for (int i : order) std::cout << func(printme[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

You've got a choice of two data structures

```
struct Employee
{
  std::string name;
  double salary;
  long payrollid;
};

std::vector<Employee> employees;
```

Or alternatively

```
struct Employees
{
   std::vector<std::string> names;
   std::vector<double> salaries;
   std::vector<long> payrollids;
};
```

C++ is designed with the first option as the default. Other languages such as Javascript tend to encourage the second option.

If you want to find mean salary, option 2 is more convenient. If you want to sort the employees by salary, option 1 is easier to work with.

However you can use lamdas to partially interconvert between the two. The lambda is a trivial little function which takes an Employee and returns a salary for him - so effectively providing a flat vector of doubles we can take the mean of - or takes an index and an Employees and returns an employee, doing a little bit of trivial data reformatting.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
template<class F>
struct index_fake_t{
  F f;
  decltype(auto) operator[](std::size_t i)const{
    return f(i);
  }
};
template<class F>
index_fake_t<F> index_fake( F f ){
  return{std::move(f)};
} 
template<class F>
auto reindexer(F f){
  return [f=std::move(f)](auto&& v)mutable{
    return index_fake([f=std::move(f),&v](auto i)->decltype(auto){
      return v[f(i)];
    });
  };
}
template<class F>
auto indexer_mapper(F f){
  return [f=std::move(f)](auto&& v)mutable{
    return index_fake([f=std::move(f),&v](auto i)->decltype(auto){
      return f(v[i]);
    });
  };
}
```

Now, print in order can be rewritten as:

```
template <typename vectorlike>
void print(vectorlike const & printme) {
  for (auto&& x:printme)
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
template <typename vectorlike>
void print_in_order(std::vector<int> const& reorder, vectorlike const & printme) {
  print(reindexer([&](auto i){return reorder[i];})(printme));
}
```

and printing `.a` as:

```
print_in_order( reorder, indexer_mapper([](auto&&x){return x.a;})(printme) );
```

there may be some typos.